# how modules can linked

Tags: linker, dotnetnuke, module

In my dotnetnuke application i added so many modules, i want to display the content in the contentpane when i clicked on the items that is in in the left / right pane. Can you give me the code for navigating the modules..

Answer (score 2):

There are a few options available to you for passing information from one module to another.  The simple way is to put the shared state on the querystring.

The more robust way is to use [Inter-Module Communication](http://kemmis.info/blog/archive/2008/02/22/dotnetnuke-inter-module-communication-or-how-your-modules-can-get-their.aspx), which basically requires one module to implement the `IModuleCommunicator` interface, allowing it to send massages.  You can then implement the `IModuleListener` interface in other modules to react to those messages.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to answer this question because I don't know what you're doing exactly.  What is the module in the left pane, and what is the module in the content pane?  How are they interacting?